# SendKey won't type some of the characters

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

I'm having bit of a issue with typing some of the special characters `SendKey.Send("~!@#$%^&*()_+|")`.

When I try to type `~!@#$%^&*()_+|`, only `!@#$*_|` is typed.

Is there way around this? Since I first collect string into `ListBox`, I could also replace these characters before actual typing. Just wondering if there's another way around this.

For the reference, this is how I end up doing this:

```
private string textToPseudo(string text)
{
    string temp = string.Empty;

    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (c == ' ')
            temp += " ";
        else
            temp += "{" + c + "}";
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: If you change the order do the same charters still not go through (like if you put a `!` between `()` does the `!` go missing?)

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain, parentheses still do not appear but exclamation point does appear. I noticed that `~` key sends return instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some characters have special significance for SendKeys. E.g. % is the Alt key, ^ is the Ctrl key, + is Shift key. You have to enclose within braces {} to use them

Comment: From the docs: [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: So the only option is to replace signs with their equivalent commands from [SendKeys Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)?

Comment: Not necessarily - you could replace each sign with itself surrounded by braces. E.g, replace '+' with '{+}'

Comment: Adding brackets will just do. Thanks mate.